# Saving a PowerPoint in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have code that creates a new powerpoint consisting of some images from an excel file. I want to save the file using a string variable to define its name. I've done my due diligence searching for solutions with no success, which surprises me based on how basic of a task I'm trying to complete. As of now, I have...

```
newPowerPoint.ActivePresentations.SaveAs filenamestring, 1
newPowerPoint.ActivePresentations.Close
```

But I keep getting a whole host of error messages. I have newPowerPoint defined as public in another module

```
Public newPowerPoint As powerpoint.Application
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you getting the error (at the `SaveAs` or at the `.Close`)?  and what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Switched out newPowerPoint with oPPTApp because of an object required error. OPPTApp is also declared as public. So the error message I'm getting now with oPPTApp is "object variable or with block variable not set" on the SaveAs line.

My Public declarations on the other module are....
Public newPowerPoint As powerpoint.Application
Public oPPTApp As Object

Comment: `Debug.Print oPPTApp Is Nothing`.  What happens in the immediates window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are dimensioning the variable oPPTApp without actually creating an instance of Powerpoint.Application.

```
Public ppApp As PowerPoint.Application

Sub PPTFile()

Dim ppPres As Presentation
Dim fileNameString As String

fileNameString = "C:\testPPT.pptx" '<change to your file path/name

'Create an instance of PPT to work with
Set ppApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
ppApp.Visible = True

'Create a new presentation (or you can access an existing file with ppApp.Presentations.Open
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

'Save:
ppPres.SaveAs fileNameString, 1

'Quit the instance of PPT that you initiated above.
ppApp.Quit

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

As you're adding slides using the AddSlide method, you need to refer to a `CustomLayout`.

```
Dim sldCount As Integer

sldCount = ppPres.Slides.count
ppPres.Slides.AddSlide sldCount + 1, ppPres.Slides(sldCount).CustomLayout
'Once you've added the slide, then set using Layout:
ppPres.Slides(sldCount + 1).Layout = ppLayoutBlank
```

Alternatively, you can use the old `.Add` method which accepts the `Layout` argument, instead of `.AddSlide` (which requires a CustomLayout):

`ppPres.Slides.Add sldCount + 1, ppLayoutBlank`

Comment: Got "Compile Error: Method or Data Member not Found" at Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

Comment: What OS & version of Excel are you using? Working fine in Excel 2010 on Win 7 XP. If you type that line in manually, the script assist should show you the available methods for `ppApp` and as long as you have enabled reference to the Powerpoint object model (without which, this code would fail to intialize) `.Add` should be an available method for `ppApp.Presentations`.   http://imgur.com/k5jj3wO  Is this not the case for you??

Comment: Hi David- Sorry for the delay...got sidetracked with another project. I am using Windows 7 Excel 2007 with ppt object model reference enabled. .Add is an available method on my screen. When running, i get this exact error: http://i.imgur.com/G5NI6KM.png?1

Any idea why?

Comment: `ActivePresentation` is not a valid member of `ppPres` which is a `Presentation`.  Try `ppPres.Slides.AddSlide ppPres.Slides.count+1 ...`

Comment: Also, that is not the same error, nor in the same place that you described before. You previously said you had an error on `ppApp.Presentations.Add`.

Comment: Thanks- looks like that got it past the error. And yes, thats correct- for whatever reason the program did not error out the same when I ran it again today. Looks like we're just about there though...i'm running into one last problem when I'm trying to define the slide type.

TypeMismatch error with "ppLayoutBlank" highlighted...
ppPres.Slides.AddSlide ppPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank

I noticed its not automatically populating a list for me to click on ppLayoutBlank after the comma....is there something else going on here?

Comment: Yes, you're trying to give it a `Layout` argument where it's expecting a `CustomLayout`.  See revision for workaround to this problem.  And if it's working for you please consider "accepting" my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will accept your answer for sure right after this question, which I believe will be my last...this is my first VBA project working with PowerPoint so thanks for sticking with me. The three lines of code giving me all this trouble are below (they reflect removal of ActivePresentation, etc.). How would I achieve what I'm trying to accomplish with my second two lines of code that currently are incorrect?
[ ppPres.Slides.Add ppPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank  (break) ppPres.GotoSlide ppPres.Slides.Count (break)
Set activeSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppPres.Slides.Count) ]

Comment: The first line is OK.  But notice that you're using `ppPres.Slides.Count` at least three times. This is a good example of where you should use a Variable instead of repeatedly calling this expression.  `Dim s as Long '(slide counter variable)` (break) `s = ppPres.Slides.Count+1` (break) `ppPres.Slides.Add s, ppLayoutBlank` (break).  So far, only minor changes to your code using the variable instead of "ppPres.Slides.Count".  Now, `ppPres.Windows(1).View.GoToSlide s` (break) `Set ActiveSlide = ppPres.Slides(s)`