# Saving using VBA: Path and file name in different cells

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, save

I am looking for a code which would save results from an excel output (CHART jpg) under given path and file name which is located under the path.

So the address (path) is located in the cell "W7".
and the file name NAME.pptx in cell "W8".

In other words,

Let in the cell "W7" be located the path to the file
and  in the cell "W8" the file name (in which a excel picutre should be saved):

```
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String

FPath = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W7")
FName = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W8")
```

How to combine the two inputs in one VBA line?

I would most appreciate your feedback. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you need help with? To concatenate the two you could just do `FullPath= Path & FileName`.

Comment: FullPath = Path & "\" & filename  I think

Comment: You might find the following useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621318/saving-a-powerpoint-in-excel-vba

Comment: You want to save it as Excel, jpg or as Powerpoint file?

Comment: Hi there, I want to save a jpg in a powerpoint file.

Comment: Do you want to export the chart into a PowerPoint presentation? This is not at all the same as saving the chart as a PowerPoint presentation. There is much involved, including code to access PowerPoint, open the presentation, copy the chart, paste onto a slide using some desired format (and BTW, jpg generally sucks for this; png is better). Search this forum or in Google for "export excel chart to powerpoint" and you'll get a lot of hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "\" & FileName, fileFormat:=52
```

Please have a look below.

Comment: It is my fault not being specific enough.
In your code you are implying to use the same path the excel file is located.
In my desired solution the path consists of two parts, the path and the file nam which are are going to be written in the give cells.

[enter image description here][1]


Please have a look at the picture.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPhIx.jpg

Comment: I kept it really short and used your variables.
With the following code you already assign the variables to Fpath and Fname:
FPath = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W7")
FName = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W8")

Then the following with your variables should save your file:
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Fpath & "\" & Fname, fileformat:=52 (if you want to save it as a *.XLSM).